# How to remove border around buttons?

Tags: java, border, button, grid-layout

I have a JPanel with the GridLayout. In every cell of the grid I have a button. I see that every button is surrounded by a gray border. I would like to remove these borders. Does anybody know how it can be done?

Answer (score 14):

```
Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
yourButton.setBorder(emptyBorder);
```

For more details on borders see the [BorderFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html)

Answer (score 12):

```java
yourButton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Answer (score 7):

In most recent Java versions it's necessary to call setContentAreaFilled(false) to remove the border entirely. Add an empty border for some padding:

```
button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's very likely the borders are part of the buttons' GUI. You could try calling `.setBorder(null)` on all the buttons and see what happens!

Comment: If you are correct in your assumption (seems reasonable to me), that would adversely affect useability.  Those borders are there partly to show which button has the input focus.

Answer (score 1):

While all of these answers work in some way, I thought I'd provide a little more in depth comparison of each along with examples.

First default buttons:

[image]

Buttons with border painted set to false removes the border and hover action but keeps the padding:

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

[image]

Buttons with a null border or empty border removes the border, hover action and padding:

```
button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

or

```
button.setBorder(null);
```

[image]

Buttons with an empty border plus dimensions removes the border and hover action and sets the padding to the provided values:

```
border.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
```

[image]

Lastly, combine these with a background and hover action to get custom matte buttons that get highlighted on hover:

```
button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
button.setBorderPainted(false);

button.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        button.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }

    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
});
```

[image]