# How do I remove this "selected" border off my button?

Tags: java, button

I am trying to create a undecorated JFrame, but I am having some issues with my Closing button, It has this ugly "selected" border around it, is there any way of removing it? (Top right corner of image)

[image: This button]

This is what I did to remove all borders and backgrounds:

```
JButton btnX = new JButton("");
    btnX.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GameHubMain.class.getResource("/Resources/Close-icon.png")));
    btnX.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnX.setOpaque(false);
    btnX.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnX.setBorderPainted(false);
    btnX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this ?

```
Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
btnX.setBorder(emptyBorder);
```

You should also try adding:

```
btnX.setFocusPainted(false);
btnX.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: The exact same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713190/how-to-remove-border-around-buttons

Comment: well because I didn't searched stackoverflow before posting my answer. Looks like someone had the idea before me. EDIT: also added some additional stuff that could help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in your code and check

```
btnX.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```